# Something is disabling my touchpad

Tags: mouse, synaptic

On YOGA 920 the touchpad is generally working, but after cloning the home directory from T420 where I rarely used it the touchpad stopped working. It's active until I log in. There is traffic when I touch it from `/dev/input/event7` but `xinput` shows it as disabled:

```
Device Enabled (138):   0
```

When I try enabling it, it's shortly enabled but something disables it immediately again:

```
Property 'Synaptics Off' changed.
    Synaptics Off (319):    0
Property 'Synaptics Off' changed.
    Synaptics Off (319):    2
Property 'Device Enabled' changed.
    Device Enabled (138):   1
Property 'Device Enabled' changed.
    Device Enabled (138):   1
Property 'Synaptics Tap Action' changed.
    Synaptics Tap Action (322): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
Property 'Synaptics Edge Scrolling' changed.
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (316): 0, 0, 0
Property 'Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling' changed.
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (317):   1, 1
Property 'Synaptics Edge Scrolling' changed.
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (316): 0, 0, 0
Property 'Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling' changed.
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (317):   1, 1
Property 'Synaptics Scrolling Distance' changed.
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (315): 29, 29
Property 'Device Enabled' changed.
    Device Enabled (138):   0
Property 'Device Enabled' changed.
    Device Enabled (138):   0
```

What could be disabling it? Maybe it's something with the Yoga Tablet mode? But the keyboard is active. The HW key is disabling the activity on `/dev/input/event7`.

Answer (score 0):

Touchpad was disabled in settings.

[image: Settings->Mouse & Touchpad]

Comment: Just to add my own "d'oh!" moment to this, I once spent ages faffing around in configs just to find I'd accidentally hit the "disable touchpad" keyboard shortcut - CTRL-F7 or similar.